# How can I prevent from deleting specific entity?

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I'm coding some back end with `SonataAdminBundle` and I need to prevent users from deleting specific entities. How can I tell the `Admin` class to prevent deletion of particular entity?

To illustrate this, think about users - usually you don't want to delete your own account or root account :) Note that I want these entities to be listed - I just don't want them to be deletable for particular users.

Comment: [Read up on Access Control Lists](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html)... it's a built-in feature with Sonata Admin. You can manage the permissions for each entity using the [ACL Editor](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#acl-editor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the permissions in SonataAdminBundle if you want to prevent certain users from deleting entities.
For example, if you want to prevent a user from deleting an entity TOTO, you just don't give him the role ROLE_NAMEOFYOURBUNDLE_ADMIN_TOTO_DELETE.

If you want to prevent all users from deleting this entity, you just need to override the configureRoutes method :

```
    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
        $collection
            ->remove('delete');
    }
```